# Is there a way to use references instead of pointers with classes that contain data to each other?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

**Problem:** Can two different classes contain values of each other without being pointers?


 I understand that in order for a class to hold another class as data inside of it it needs to know that the other class exists in the code. So this is done by forward declaration. Forward declaration does not mean that it has been defined yet so in order for a class to hold it before it gets defined it needs to be pointing towards it. 


I have a couple different valid ways of accomplishing this faultlessly, but I'd preferably use references over raw pointers so I won't have to worry about a pointer getting deleted some where in future code.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code as I was writing this question, and it works. I decided to post this question in case any one in the future thought about the same thing. And I also wanted to see if my answer/solution was a good one.

```
class child;
class parent{
public:
    child &myKid;
    std::string name;
    parent( child &kid ):myKid(kid){ name = "Dave"; }
};
class child{
public:
    parent &adult;
    child( parent& vAdult ):adult(vAdult){}
    //child( parent* vAdult ):adult(vAdult){ }
};

int main()
{
child jame( *(new parent( jame )) );
parent &Dave =  jame.adult;
std::cout<< Dave.name << std::flush;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoeZ I see a problem in the code. `child jame( *(new parent( jame )) )` means that `adult` in `jame` has an undefined reference to a child.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that will free the `parent`.  When `child` goes out of scope, you've leaked the `parent`.  You can try to fix it by adding a destructor to `child` that does something crazy like `delete &adult`, but I don't think you can write correct copy or copy-assignment constructors, so you end up violating the Rule-of-3.  You would have to make your class un-copyable, which is rather inconvenient.

Comment: @JoeZ I just noticed that after I reread the code and noticed that `new` means it was placed inside the free memory store and it will never be deleted. And I see the other problem you just mentioned as well. Back to the drawing boards.